# Generate keypair using NEAR Lib

Tags: nearprotocol

My current code snippet to create a KeyPair is

```
const nearLib = require("nearlib");

const keyRandom = nearLib.utils.KeyPairEd25519.fromRandom(); 
console.log(keyRandom);
console.log(keyRandom.getPublicKey());
```

My output for the public key of my KeyPair is

```
PublicKey {
  keyType: 0,
  data: Uint8Array [
     86,  17,  27, 168, 244, 140, 239, 176,
    142, 254, 255, 212, 141, 228,  99, 185,
     50, 153, 127, 160, 174,  91, 203,  42,
     84,   0, 187,  25,   6, 138, 241,  84
  ]
}
```

What on earth is this? Was expecting a base 58 public key, not a Uint8Array, I could probably cast it to base58? Unsure of exactly how to proceed here or why it is displaying in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.toString()` on the returned public key. Something like:

```
console.log(keyRandom.publicKey.toString());
```

That'll return key as base58 encoded string.